# Google Sheet API: Printing only on the first sheet - Java

Tags: java, servlets, google-sheets

I am able to manipulate data on the first sheet but I not in the second. On the API page, it states that the range must indicate the sheet tab name. so I did that and it compiles and runs but it enters data to the Sheet1 instead of Sheet Two.

**This is what the tabs look like:**

[image: This is what the tabs look like].

Any help of is much appreciated, Thank you in advance

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class SheetsQuickstart {
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "CSC131";
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials//sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart.json");
private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList( SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS );
private static String spreadsheetId = "1BLt5iz1udvdrbxPAoHbgxNtpqgKmV_fvvAKGWPJekyM";

static {
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println("Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}


public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {
    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
} 


/********************* Stores comment in cell *****************/
public static void inputComment(int col, String Comment, String ID)throws IOException{
    Sheets service = getSheetsService();
    final String range = "Sheet Two!C2:C26";
    ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range).execute();
    List<List<Object>> element = response.getValues();
    int cellRow = 0;
    for (List row : element) {
        cellRow++;
        if(ID.equals(row.get(0))){
            printInfo(cellRow,col,Comment);
            break;
        }           
    } 
}



/********************* Prints everything *****************/
public static void printInfo(int row, int count, String Date) throws IOException{
    Sheets service = getSheetsService();
    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

    List<CellData> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(new CellData().setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue().setStringValue((Date))));
    requests.add(new Request()
        .setUpdateCells(new UpdateCellsRequest()
        .setStart(new GridCoordinate().setSheetId(0).setRowIndex(row).setColumnIndex(count+6))
        .setRows(Arrays.asList(new RowData().setValues(values)))
        .setFields("userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor")));     
    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requests);
    service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batchUpdateRequest).execute();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in `printInfo()` - note the `new GridCoordinate().setSheetId(0)`.

If in doubt the sheetId comes from the `SheetProperties` - e.g. from `Spreadsheet.getSheets()....getProperties()`.

Comment: If i could give you a hug, I would. Thanks so much. I don't know why i didn't catch that when i wrote it.